# Class template constructor default arguments

Tags: c++, constructor, default-parameters

I am trying to make the constructor to set default values for template types as following:

With this struct template

```
template<class Type1, class Type2>
struct Pair
```

This is my constructor:

```
Pair(const Type1& t1 = Type1(), const Type2& t2 = Type2()) :
first(t1), second(t2)
{}
```

I use calls to the default constructor of each type.
Everything goes with if I call the constructor with params:

```
Pair<float, double> pair_fd(1, 1);
```

But when I make the call without params the program gives linker errors.

Is possible to achieve what i am trying? If so, what am I missunderstanding?

Thank you all.

Comment: _"Is possible to achieve what i am trying?"_ Yes. _"If so, what am I missunderstanding?"_ There ar many ways this can fail, show a [MCVE] please.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/936667f11b5b06a0). My link is an example of an MCVE.

Comment: Why not just make a default constructor for `Pair` and use `std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible<Type1>::value>` (similarly for `Type2`)? Or just use `std::pair` instead of making a custom pair type.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury, That's probably overly complicated for what the OP needs (the SFINAE, not the standard pair). I assume this is a learning exercise or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I was trying to create the variable like

```
Pair<float, double> pair_fd();
```

Instead of

```
Pair<float, double> pair_fd;
```

Thanks @chris